# According to srimad bhagvatam and Vishnu purana is saguna brahman superior to nirguna brahman?

Tags: puranas, bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana, brahman, vishnu-purana

How is the relation of of parmatma-brahman- bhagvan shown in sattvic puranas, is saguna brahman the basis of nirguna brahman as found in some verse of bhagvad geeta?

I'm asking this as bhagvatam plays a major role in gaudiya vaishnava beliefs and Vishnu purana in other vaishnava sects. Bhagvatam is also considered commentary on Brahma sutras by vyasa(by some and garuda purana), so who do these puranas claim to be supreme?

Comment: Related: [Why does Krishna consider/believe the devotee who worship him as saguna superior than who worship as nirguna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11520/277)